# Drawing conclusions from Cantor's Diagonal Argument

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

Given the set $B$ of all possible sequences of binary digits of finite length ("finite binary sequences"), construct a finite binary sequence $S$ such that each member of the sequence is the logical negation of the corresponding submember of the corresponding member of $B$, or because that sounds a bit ridiculous: $$\textrm{let}\ S = \{ S_n \ | \ S_n = \neg{B_{n_n}} \forall n \in [1, 2, 3,...] \}$$

$$B_1 = {\color{blue}{1}, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,...} \\ B_2 = {0, \color{blue}{1}, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,...} \\ B_3 = {1, 0, \color{blue}{0}, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,...} \\ B_4 = {1, 0, 0, \color{blue}{1}, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,...} \\ B_5 = {1, 1, 0, 0, \color{blue}{1}, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0,...} \\ B_6 = {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, \color{blue}{0}, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,...} \\ B_7 = {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, \color{blue}{1}, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,...} \\ B_8 = {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, \color{blue}{0}, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,...} \\ B_9 = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, \color{blue}{1}, 1, 0, 1, 0,...} \\ B_{10} = {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, \color{blue}{1}, 0, 0, 1,...} \\ B_{11} = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, \color{blue}{1}, 0, 0,...} \\ B_{12} = {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, \color{blue}{1}, 1,...} \\ B_{13} = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, \color{blue}{0},...} \\ \vdots \\ ------------------- \\ \ \ \ S = {\color{red}{0}, \color{red}{0}, \color{red}{1}, \color{red}{0}, \color{red}{0}, \color{red}{1}, \color{red}{0}, \color{red}{1}, \color{red}{0}, \color{red}{0}, \color{red}{0}, \color{red}{0}, \color{red}{1},...}$$

Because each member $S_n$ of $S$ is *defined* as the logical negation of the corresponding value in the corresponding member of $B$, $S$ *cannot* be equal to *any* member of $B$. $S$ differs from $B_1$ at position $1$, $B_2$ at position $2$, $B_3$ at position $3$, and so on. So $S$ is not in $B$. And we've got a contradiction.

We defined $B$ as the set of possible finite binary sequences, and yet we created a set $S$ that is both a finite binary sequence and not in $B$, so where's the contradiction? Considering I never tried to *construct* $B$ but was simply provided it as the set of all possible binary sequences, am I to conclude that it is simply impossible for a set to contain all possible binary sequences? Or that it is impossible to evaluate membership of such a set? Or perhaps that because the sequences are by definition of finite length, there simply aren't enough digits to accommodate negating all possible members of $B$?

I'm a bit confused, because while I understand the theory behind the use of this diagonal argument in proof, there's a logical contradiction where it seems all math is sound. Things get even more odd when the requirement for the sequences to be of finite length is dropped and $B$ is made to be the set of all possible binary sequences. What am I missing?

Comment: Why should $S$, defined this way, be finite?

Comment: Do you have a typo somewhere in this sentence?  `We defined B as the set of possible finite binary sequences, and yet we created a set S that is both a finite binary sequence and not in B, so where's the contradiction?`

Comment: Since we have infinite many lines, $S$ must be an infinite sequence.

Comment: @Peter I thought of that, and it gets tricky right there. There are infinitely many sequences of finite length, in that you could never find the last one. And yet in the same grain, you could never find the last digit of the last member of $B$. So the number of digits matches the number of elements such that it works out, as far as I can tell. But if this is where the contradiction is, please let me know

Comment: S most certainly is not finite.  However if you were given every sequence of *infinitely* countable sequences you *would* get a contradiction.  And the resolution of *that* would be that there is no countable list of all countable seqences and the nmber of *infinite* sequence is not countable.  Here the set of finite sequences *is* countable but if you made an finite list of all seqences you would get a contradiction that is resolved in that the set of all finite sequences is not finite.

Comment: What is "the last member of $B$"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber haha that one really pained me to write out. The point being that the length of $S$ is limited by the length of the elements of $B$, so as far as I can reason length shouldn't be a factor limiting its membership in $B$, as every member came from an _equally-large_ member of $B$ to the length up to that index, ad infinitum

Comment: "The point being that the length of S is limited by the length of the elements of B"  which are completely unlimited.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist No, its length is **absolutely** a factor limiting its membership in $B$. $B$ is the set of **finite sequences**. $S$ is not finite, any more than the set of natural numbers is finite (even though each natural number itself is finite). Do you understand this?

Comment: Instead of listing *all* sequences lets list *some* sequences.  And lets list them so that $B_1$ has length 1.  And let $B_2$ have length $2$ and $B_k$ has lenghth $k$.  So how long are the longest members?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist Note that this is *exactly the same* difficulty you had in [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663116/is-an-infinitely-long-integer-in-the-natural-numbers); you are having trouble distinguishing actually-finite things from infinite objects which are "built out of" finite pieces.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It would indeed seem so. To help me understand, answer me this: If $S$ gets its $n^{th}$ member from the $n^{th}$ member of $B_n$, and we can agree that $S$ is infinite in length, then $S$ is clearly longer than nearly every member of $B$. And yet $S$ can't be longer than _every_ member of $B$, because it needs sources for its members. I have no problem seeing that $S$ is longer than infinitely many members of $B$, but I can't see how any closed set of axioms allows $S$ to be strictly larger than _every_ member of $B$ when it draws its length directly from that of $B$'s members.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist "And yet $S$ can't be longer than every member of $B$, because it needs sources for its members." That's nonsense. $S$ can indeed be longer than every element in $B$, because there's no *single* element of $B$ that $S$ relies on. $S$ gets to draw on *all* the elements of $B$, and $B$ has arbitrarily long elements.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'll play the other side for a minute. Let's take this at face value and agree that $S$ is indeed strictly longer than _every_ member of $B$. Because of what strictly longer means, and because its length is discrete, and as such can change by values no smaller than 1, it must be _at least 1 larger_ than every element of $B$. And yet if it is at least 1 larger than every element of $B$, then it has a member that is not present at member $n$ in _any_ member of $B$. This is a contradiction, as its members all come from the matching indices of $B_n$, _a member of_ $B$.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist No, that's not right. You're conflating "For each element $f$ of $B$, there is some initial segment of $S$ of length greater than that of $f$" with "There is some initial segment of $S$ of length greater than that of every element of $B$." That is, you're conflating "$\forall \exists$" with "$\exists \forall$". This is not a thing you can do. For instance, the statement "For every number $x$, there is a number $y$ such that $x<y$" is true, but the statement "There is a number $y$ such that for every number $x$, $x<y$" is false. This is a fundamental error.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I really appreciate this discussion by the way. I'm learning a lot of exactly what I wanted to learn, so I'm really thankful you're taking the time to help. Here's my current perspective, if you wouldn't mind please break it somewhere: Either $S$ is strictly larger than all elements of $B$, or it isn't, because, well, there is no third option between is and isn't. Now if $S$ isn't strictly larger than all elements of $B$, then because the inverse of _strictly larger than all_ is _no larger than some_ the size of $S$ is bounded by some elements of $B$....

Comment: ... Given that _all_ elements of $B$ are finite, so then is $S$. Alternatively, $S$ _is_ strictly larger than _all_ members of $B$, in which case, because _larger_ in the context of the discrete number of elements in a set means _has more elements_, $S$ has more elements than _all_ members $B_n$ of $B$, so there exists some $S_n$ for which $B_{n_n}$ does not exist, which defies the definition of $S$. Either $S$ is strictly larger, leading to a logical contradiction, or $S$ is not strictly larger, leading to a logical contradiction.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist "$S$  has more elements than all members BnBn of BB, so there exists some $S_n$ for which $B_n$ does not exist" **No, that's not true**. Again, you're mixing up the logic: just because no single $B_n$ provides all the digits of $S$, does *not* mean that there's some digit of $S$ which is inaccessible from every element of $B$. This is exactly the same mistake as before: you need to realize that "For every $x$, there is some $y$ such that [stuff]" is not the same as "There is some $y$ such that, for every $x$, [stuff]."

Comment: You are falling into a very common stumbling block.  For each one of the many $S_n$ there will be a $_nB$ that is length equal or longer than $n$.  From that you are making a mistake that  therefore the most be some single $_{\alpha}B$ that is longer than all $S_n$.  This is *not* true because the $_nB$ that are each longer than some $S_n$ are different and there is not *one* $_{\alpha}B$ that works for all.  This is *EXACTLY* the same as: for every $n$ there is an $m > n$ therefore there is some $m$ larger than every number.  So all numbers are less than $m$ and $m$ is the largest number.

Comment: "S has more elements than all members $B_n$ of B, so there exists some $S_n$ for which $B_{n_n}$ does not exist".  Why do you believe that.  That simply not true.  For any $S_n$ there is a $B_{m_n}$ that is longer than $S_n$.  But so what?  There is also an $S_{p_{m_n}}$ longer than $B_{m_n}$.  And $S$ is longer than all of these.

Comment: Infinite sets and intuition don't mix well. Consider the set of all natural nunbers up to a maximum m, N(m). Every member of the set is finite, and its cardinality is finite. Similarly, every member of the set of all finite numbers N is finite, but its cardinality is infinite. This seems like a contradiction to many, but it is a fundamental property you need to grasp before you can understand Cantor. In this question, B can only be constructed if you know that len(Sn)<=n, or you pad each with infinite zeros. Either way, S has that same unintuitive property, that it's length has to be infinite.

Comment: @JeffJo Am I wrong in assuming that this behavior is largely arbitrary, i.e. we could have made infinities behave in a few different ways, but because we chose this particular path, all the resulting mathematics functions in this way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but I think the answer is "no". We can make infinite sets "behave" in many different was that would be contradictory if they were finite, and it happens with all of them. You can match the set of all natural numbers 1:1 with the even natural numbers by the relation e=2n. In fact, Cantor defines an infinite set as one that can be put in a 1:1 with a subset of itself, so there is nothing arbitrary about it. Your S has to be infinite because it has to have a character in position n, for every n in N.

Answer (score 2):

> We defined $B$ as the set of possible finite binary sequences, and yet we created a set $S$ that is both a finite binary sequence and not in $B$, so where's the contradiction?

The contradiction is exactly what you said:  You constructed an $S$ that by definition of $B$ should be in $B$ but is not in $B$.

Did you perhaps mean to say $S$ is an *infinite* binary sequence?  In that case, yes, there is no contradiction.  In fact, the set of all finite binary sequences is indeed countable.

I believe the confusion you're having is because you're applying Cantor's diagonal argument to the wrong thing.  The original diagonal argument was applied to the set of all **infinite** binary sequences, not the set of all **finite** binary sequences.  So your definition of $B$ must be adjusted.

Comment: I'm not trying to duplicate Cantor directly, I'm asking a reduced version, and one that, to the best I can tell, is a perfectly valid argument to make regardless of whether applied to the finite or to the infinite

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist What do you mean by "reduced version"?  It isn't valid for finite because (1) as you pointed out (assuming you did in fact mean to say that $S$ is infinite, which it is) there is no contradiction and (2) the set $B$ as you defined is not uncountable, so no proof that it is uncountable will be valid.

Answer (score 1):

> and yet we created a set $S$ that is both a finite binary sequence and not in $B$,

Why do you think $S$ is finite? In fact, it's easy to show that it *won't* be - and this resolves your difficulty.

Comment: The length of $S$ is, because of its member-by-member construction, no larger than the length of the longest elements in $B$, it qualifies as a member of $B$ just as much as any other member of $B$, no?

Comment: There is not longest element in B.  Just as there is no largest finite number.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist And what do you think is "the length of the longest element in $B$"? Do you think there is a largest natural number?

Comment: The fact that the elements are themselves finite and bounded, does not mean the set of all of them is finite and bounded.  There is no longest sequence as for any sequence of length k one can make a sequence of length k+1.  As the list is infinitite the sequense S is infinite.

Comment: "it qualifies as a member of B just as much as any other member of B, no?"  No.  It most certainly does not.

Comment: @fleablood Hmm, I'd really appreciate if you expanded that logic to an answer so I can think it over and try to understand

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist Let's start small. Do you understand why the set of natural numbers is not finite?

Comment: Okay.  Suppose S is finite.  How long is it?  Say it is $k$ long.  But then what is $S_{k+1}$.  If $S$ is finite there can not be any $S_{k+1}$ term.  But you defined it so that $S_{k+1} = \lnot B_{k+1,k+1}$.  So there is an $S_{k+1}$ term.  S is not finite.  For any $k$ there is a finite sequence that is $k$ long.  ANd there are an infinite number of possible $k$s.  There is *no* longest $k$.

Comment: For any finite number $n$ there is another finite number $n+1$.  So there is no largest natural number.  And for any finite sequence that is $n$ long, there is another that is $n+1$ long.  So there is no longest finite sequence.  So S is *not* bounded by the longest sequences because there *aren't* any longest sequences.

Answer (score 1):

One inconsistancy, that is !!!!!NOT!!!!! the error, is that you define $S_n$ as $\lnot B_{n,n}$. But as $B_n$ is finite, what is $S_n$ if $B_n$ has length shorter than $n$ (and as there are $2^k$ sequences that are length $k$ and $2^k > k$ there *must* be some $B_n$ that are shorter than length $n$[$*$]).

!!!!THIS IS NOT THE ERROR!!!!!!.

We can define $S_1 = \lnot B_{1,1}$. Then $S \ne B_1$.  If $B_{2}$ through $B_{k}$ are less than $2$ long, don't do anything. Let $i_2$ be such that $B_{i_2}$ is the first sequence after $B_1$ that is larger than equal to $2$.  Then let $S_2 = \lnot B_{i_2, 2}$.  This way $S \ne B_1$.  $S \ne B_{2}$ through $B_{i_2-1}$ (as those are all shorter than length $2$ and $S \ne B_{i_2}$ as $S_2 \ne B_{i_2, 2}$.

Continue so that $S_n = \lnot B_{i_n, n}$.  Then $S$ will not equal any of the $B_i$ and each term is well defined.

But as every $S_n$ exist, that means $S$ is ***INFINITE***.  Your insistence that $S$ is finite is bizarre as for every possible $n$ an $S_n$ term exist so there are an infinite number of terms.  So $S$ is ***CLEARLY*** infinite.

You confusion seems to lie in that every finite *SUB*sequence of $S$ from $S_1.....S_m$ is finite and is shorter than some $B_{i_m}$ that somehow $S$ the sequence that contains *all* the terms must be shorter than some $B_{i_m}$.  That is simply wrong.

For any $S_1.... S_n$ there is some $B_m$ that is longer but there is *NOT* !one! $B_m$ that is longer than *all* $S_1 ..... S_k$. For each $S_1..... S_n$ there is a *DIFFERENT* $B_m$ that is longer.  And there is *NO* $B_m$ that is longer than *ALL* $S_1...S_n$.

Which really should be obvious... So $S$ is very clearly and inarguably infinite.

Comment: I _really_ like this answer, the conclusion being that there simply aren't enough values of $B_n$ to construct S. But that would mean that $S$ _cannot_ be drawn from $B$. The problem I have is stating that $S$ _can_ be drawn from $B$, _and_ $S$ can be infinite while all $B_n$ are not

Comment: But...no.  that *isn't* the issue.  The issue is simply that S is defined to have an infinite number of terms.  So it isn't finite.

Comment: Is an infinitely large sequence required to be strictly larger than any and all sequences of finite length?

Comment: What does "larger than all" mean?  Yes, it is longer than any.  But "longer than all" doesn't have any meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I sense you are not seeing the forest for the trees. 
Cantor's diagonal argument shows that the reals cannot be put in a list.   The reals have the same cardinality as the power set of the integers. This shows the power set $P (\mathbb Z) $ has higher cardinality than $\mathbb Z $.  The result generalizes to power sets of any set.  It's easy to prove there is no surjection from a set to its power set.  Given  $f:X\rightarrow P (X) $, define y in P(X) by $y=\{x|x \notin f(x)\}.$  Then y is not in the image of f. No surjection  means the power set has higher cardinality.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what "cannot be put in a list" means? I can understand that such a list cannot be _constructed_ by any algorithm. That would be consistent with undecidability and Gödel incompleteness. I can accept that there's no way of making such a list, but how can they _not be put in a list_? {ℝ} there, that's the list. How doesn't that work?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist given such a list of numbers,  I can produce a number you have left out...  by simply going along the diagonal and constructing a number which differs from the ith number in the list in the ith place after the decimal. ..

Comment: A list is broadly defined (and very intentionally so) as a collection of items, with or without an associated ordering. A collection of items is... just a collection of items. The pile of bananas on my counter is a collection of items. The keys on this keyboard are a collection of items. How are the reals not a collection of items? There's something profoundly nonsensical about the notation that a list, or set if you like, defined only as a collection of things, cannot contain a certain well-defined collection of things

Comment: They're an uncountable collection. ..

Comment: That's vocabulary

Answer (score 0):

Cantor's diagonal argument is almost always misrepresented, even by those who claim to understand it. This question get one point right - it is about binary strings, not real numbers. In fact, it was SPECIFICALLY INTENDED to NOT use real numbers.

But another thing that is misrepresented, is that it is a proof by contradiction. It isn't, and actually can't be. A proof by contradiction has to show that a contradiction follows from what was assumed, and it has to follow from ALL of what is assumed. Let me give a silly example. Assume the moon is made of a combination of bleu and green cheese, in a ratio that is equal to the square root of two. A well-known use of proof by contradiction is that if you assume a ratio is the square root of two, you get a contradiction about the factors in that ratio. This proves that there can't be a ratio equal to the square root of two. But it doesn't prove anything about the cheeses that make up the moon, even if you include that in your assumption. The contradiction does not follow from the assumed cheeses.

That the anti-diagonal string is not in your list does not follow from assuming you had a list of ALL strings. Only that you had a list of SOME strings. So all it proves is that any list of SOME strings can't be ALL. But that is enough: proving "if A, then B" also proves "if not B, then not A." This is called proof by controposition, not contradiction.

The basic outline of the proof is:
1) Assume T is the entire set you are interested in.
2) Assume S is a countable subset of T.
3) Create the anti-diagonal string of S, called D, which cannot be in S.
4) Prove that D is in T.
5) This proves "If S is Countable, it is not all of T."
6) By contraposition, "If S is all of T, it is not countable."

Where the argument in the original question fails, is step 4. The anti-diagonal it called S must be infinite since it is a function of the infinite set B. Therefore it isn't supposed to be in B.

Answer (score 0):

First understand that the proposed set $B$ is a countably infinite set of finite sets and is isomorphic to the rational numbers, and is possible to construct.

When you construct the diagonal $S$ across the entire list, that will produce another countably infinite set. So you are comparing apples to oranges. The list $B$ has finite sets and the diagonal $S$ is a countably infinite set.

If you still want to try to define a finite set $S$ out of the diagonal then that set will have a last element located at the end of some $B_X$ in the main set $B$. Later on at some at some point $B_Y$ the $S$ string will appear if the list 
is really complete.

Either way there is no contradiction involved.